# How to chmod by file extension to remove execute permission on some file types?

Tags: ubuntu, chmod, file-extension

I have searched but couldn't find a proper way to do that. I find annoying that each time I click on a text or code file I have a prompt where I can execute the file (maybe it's me that messed up permissions...)

I would like to get rid of that as I know some file extesions would never be executables: `*.js,*.php,*.txt,*.md,*.css,*.json`...etc.

I have tried that:

```
sudo find . -name "*.js" -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

But noticed that it doesn't change anything...

tried also

```
chmod -R -x *.js
```

but that outputed an error

Please light my way :)